# Volume Control not showing in Ubuntu Unity Top Panel

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

For some reason volume control widget is not showing on my Ubuntu panel. I reinstalled alsa and something else, because my sound broke. Now I can't get my audio control panel to display on Unity main panel.

Any one knows what is the problem?

Comment: Did you start Pithos? Sometimes that will kill the sound icon.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. This will help others by indicating that it is a valid answer that worked for you. If it didn't, please respond to requests for further information. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

**For 14.04 and 16.04** From the launcher - System Settings -> Sound make sure the box shown at bottom left is checked.

Alternatively you can launch from the command line with `unity-control-center sound`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Testing indicates that this works as well on both 14.04 and 16.04